# Outlaw setting Corona SDK wierd issue with addressing

Tags: coronasdk

So this is the problem I have with my Outlaw:

My Corona SDK is in that adress:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Corona Labs\Corona SDK\Corona Simulator.exe

I'm going to Preferences --> Corona SDK simulator --> puts this adress.

once I'm trying to lunch my program, Outlaw says this:

"Windows cannot find 'C:\Program\". make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again"

I've figures it doesn't recognise spaces (lamest thing ever). what the hell should I do? I don't want to mobilize my entire computer to non-spaced folders.

Comment: Are you trying to launch the simulator from the command prompt? Put quotes around the entire path, ex: `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Corona Labs\Corona SDK\Corona Simulator.exe'`

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled to the same problem trying to use Outlaw on Windows. I've tried adding quotes, tried options with PATH, but ultimately I've to just gave up. 
Apparently author *never* tested his app under Windows :)

As a side note I can recommend [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) as an excellent alternative. It's free and works great with Corona.

Comment: Outlaw is not only tested on Windows, but a big chunk of the users are on Windows. I don't find your name in any tech support emails, but it's possible I missed it. Sorry you had problems, but glad you found something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Browse button in Prefs to point to the simulator exe; don't type in the pathname. I should probably make that field read-only so you *have* to use the Browse button.